# CardView colapsses my AS app at runtime, how can I use CardView appropriately?

Tags: android, android-cardview

I have a simple application which collapses as I run it. When I remove the `CardView` view the app runs appropriately.

> How can I add the `CardView` view appropriately?

I suspect that the right decleration of the `CardView` view should be different then: `android.support.v7.widget.CardView`.

Here's `activity.main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's `build.gradle` (Module: app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "android.example.blah1111"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:29.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITED

You have `appcompat` dependency, which contains correct version of `CardView`. So, just change the reference from `android.com` to `androidx` in your XML. Don't forget to get rid of old unused dependency.
Also take a look at this article https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: Actually the specific line `androidx.cardview:cardview` did not help me, but when I typed `androidx.` AS suggested me to use the decleration `androidx.cardview.widget.CardView` which solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: `com.android.support:cardview-v7:29.0.0` does not exist and should be removed.